# Java - Casting typed list to array

Tags: java, arrays, list, reflection

This is my method

```
public AuctionItem[] getOpenAuctions() throws RemoteException {

    return itemList.toArray((AuctionItem[]) java.lang.reflect.Array
            .newInstance(itemList.getClass(), itemList.size()));

}
```

and this is my error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.util.LinkedList; cannot be cast to [LAuction.AuctionItem;
at Auction.AuctionImpl.getOpenAuctions(AuctionImpl.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at $Proxy0.getOpenAuctions(Unknown Source)
at Seller.SellerMain.main(SellerMain.java:38)
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
return itemList.toArray(new AuctionItem[itemList.size()]);
```

The problem with the code you wrote is that `itemList.getClass()` returns the class `LinkedList`.  So the `Array.newInstance()` method is creating a `LinkedList[]`, which you are then trying to typecast to an `AuctionItem[]`.  Since these two types are incompatible for assignment, it throws a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

`itemList.getClass()` returns `LinkedList.class`, because it is a LinkedList.  `itemList.peek().getClass()` would fix this, but only if the list has at least one element.

Why not just:

```
public AuctionItem[] getOpenAuctions() {
    return itemList.toArray(new AuctionItem[itemList.size()]);
}
```